# IE7 z-index bug

Tags: internet-explorer, z-index

[removed URL]

The drop down menu should, obviously, appear above the "bubble" images. It works in every other browse apart from IE7, any ideas?

I've Googled it but it doesn't seem to give me a solution to my problem

Comment: I managed to fix it by giving the parent elements (All of them) a `position:relative;` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion: Do the drop-down menu points have "a layout"? This can mess up IE's interpretatino of z-index.

Try adding `zoom: 1;` or `position: relative;` to the li elements.

Comment: They already have `position:relative;` and `zoom:1;` doesn't seem to have any effect.